# Segue to ViewController semi automatically (seems to work)

Tags: swift, uiviewcontroller, segue

I want to jump to another Viewcontroller resulting from the actions of a UIAlertController. I have read that you can't segue programmatically and have found a quick semi-fix which appears too simple and want to get peoples' views.

In the code to setup some MultipeerConnectivity is an UIAlertController, see below.

```
        func showConnectionPrompt() {
            let ac = UIAlertController(title: "Connect to Others", message: nil, preferredStyle: .actionSheet)
            ac.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Host Play session", style: .default, handler: startHosting))
            ac.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Join Play session", style: .default, handler: joinSession))
            ac.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Cancel", style: .cancel, handler: noSession))
            present(ac, animated: true)
        }
```

Take the call from "Host Play session"...

```
    func startHosting(action: UIAlertAction!) {
        status = "start"
        mcAdvertiserAssistant = MCAdvertiserAssistant(serviceType: "Play", discoveryInfo: nil, session: mcSession)
        mcAdvertiserAssistant.start()
        performSegue(withIdentifier: "Controller", sender: nil)
    }
```

See the call to the Segue called "Controller"? I put a button on the original ViewController - linked it to the recipient and called the Identifier "Controller".

Is this an acceptable approach?
Can I remove the button which is there just to create the Segue link because I know no other way of doing this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The right way to do this would be creating a segue from your view controller to the desired destination view controller. You do not need a button to do this. You can create a segue from a view controller by CTRL + Dragging to the destination view controller.

**Update:**

If you can't CTRL + Drag from the view controller scene, drag from the view controller in the sidebar:

[image]

Comment: I tried that but the segue doesn't latch on the destination - what's the trick?

Comment: Updated...CTRL+Drag from the source view controller in the sidebar.

Comment: Many thanks - forgot where the connection came from. Irrelevant question with hindsight. Thank you for curing the amnesia.